# Plot 2 variables on the same axis

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot both y1 and y2 against x.

I don't want to use `ggplot2`.

Is it possible with just the `plot()` function? I have tried using `par(new = TRUE)` but this literally overlays y2 with y1 and it looks messy. I want to color code it for both y1 and y2.

Grateful for any pointers. Thanks

Comment: you can add variables with `points()` also you can use the col argument there. Check `?points()`

Comment: Just curious, why you don't want to use ggplot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot two graphs in same plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564258/plot-two-graphs-in-same-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add variables with `points()` also you can use the col argument there. Check `?points()` for more information. Here a small example with a costum dataset.

```
df<-mtcars
plot(df$disp, df$mpg)
points(df$hp, df$mpg, col="green")
```

Output:

[image: plot]

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! But how should I add a legend to describe which col relates to which variable?

Comment: This is such a basic concept in R that it's almost guaranteed to be a duplicate. Please do a search before you answer.

Comment: @HenryP. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401702/add-legend-to-a-plot-with-r) or ?legend